# Devolver un combo box a estado inicial VB6

Tags: vb6

Devolver un combo box a estado inicial  (vacio) estando en style 2 - dropdown list, tengo un combo box con las marcas de unos autos, y la tengo en style 2-dropdown list, para que el usuario no pueda escribir nada, solo elegir, pero luego tengo un botón de limpiar, y yo habia puesto ComboMarca.text = "", pero me dice que la propiedad text es solo lectura, y es porque está en style 2-dropdown list, como lo devuelvo a el estado inicial cuando ingreso por primera vez al formulario, o sea en blanco?

Comment: Prueba con `ComboMarca.RowSource=""`

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes Te animas a hacer una respuesta completa con eso?

Comment: @gbianchi Disculpa, no entiendo tu comentario. ¿que lo publique como respuesta?

Comment: Si eso soluciona el problema, haz una respuesta completa con eso. @ElierSánchezE-Infantes

Comment: Proba haciendo un clear y un refresh sobre el combo y volver a cargar la info

Comment: PAra limpiarlo Combo1.ListIndex = -1

Answer (score 1):

```
ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
```

Con eso ya puedes limpiar todos los elementos de tu **`ComboBox`**.

Comment: Vaya, hicieron una evaluación negativa de mi publicación, quisiera saber si el que hizo la evaluación sabe algo de Visual Basic como para evaluar mal lo que puse.